# Unable to uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 from Wubi

Tags: 12.04, wubi, uninstall

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 using wubi, I lost my user interface on ubuntu after uninstalling pyhon by mistake... now I want to uninstall ubuntu but uninstall-wubi  is not diong anything after double clicking on it... what should I do now

Comment: Did you try uninstall from Windows Add/Remove Programs?

Comment: This wubi you installed, was it installed inside Windows or on another partition...?

Comment: yes i tried from uninstall from Windows Add/Remove Programmes but nothing is happening...Also it is installed on other partition...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows, and go to partition(e.g.: `C:` `D:` `E:` etc) where you have installed Ubuntu, open Ubuntu folder, there you can find `uninstall-wubi.exe` application file. By clicking this you can uninstall Ubuntu from your system.

Another option,

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Select *Programs and features*
3. Click *"Ubuntu"*
4. Click *Uninstall/Change*
5. Follow the instructions.

Comment: I tried both options.... But nothing is happening... I also tried by logging in Ubuntu ... it is nothing showing except wall.. also I tried to open terminal by Alt+Ctrl+t but it is not showing it

Comment: Should I format may other drive??? But How can I reinstall it??

Comment: send screen shot of windows drive where you installed ubuntu, show me the ubuntu folder also..